# How to use Available Package instead of Installed Package when Yum spits out a required error

Tags: php, php7, phpmyadmin

First and foremost, I blindly followed a tutorial to upgrade from PHP 7.3 to PHP 7.4, which called for `yum remove "php*" -y`
Of course this just screwed up everything.  It removed two very important apps, including `roundcubemail` and `phpmyadmin`

Now what I get is certain packages cannot be installed, and spits out this, as an example:

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-zip-1.20.0-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64 (remi)
       Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
       Installed: php-common-7.4.27-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php74)
           php(zend-abi) = 20190902-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 (base)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
```

Now, under available, you have `php-common-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64` which carries the `php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64` version needed.  Now according to Yum... this is installed:
`Package matching php-common-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.`

My question is, how can I force it detect the available version, instead of the installed version, as the available version is installed and has the right version.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I uninstalled all PHP from my system, including php5.  Enabled the remi-php74 repo and installed fresh... no longer had issues installing PHPMyadmin and Roundcudemail